# You cannot specify tags for Spot instances requests if there are no Spot instances requests being created by the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created a spot request. In the logs I see:

> You cannot specify tags for Spot instances requests if
> there are no Spot instances requests being created by the request.

Could anyone explain the error message in plain English, please? The text makes no sense to me as non-English native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ther error happens when you are trying to tag a non-existent resource.

One example will be want to propagate a name in cfn template, but there was not spot created

```
LaunchTemplate:
  Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
  Properties:
    LaunchTemplateName: some-name
    LaunchTemplateData:
      TagSpecifications:
        - ResourceType: spot-instances-request
          Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: some-name
```

Comment: So, we cannot define tags in LaunchTemlate? Where they should be defined then, to propagate properly?

Comment: You can, as long as you have spot instances coming up.  But let's say you have a mixed instance policy where you want to bring up 1 on-demand and 1 spot-instances and your on-demand base capacity is set to 1, everything comes up fine,. Now for a certain interval/scenario, you upped the on-demand base capacity to 2. Now for the app, you have 2 on-demand and 0 spots. This is when there will be no spot-instance request and the ASG will barf the error.

Comment: One powerful feature cloudformation have that is sparsely used is the cfn tagging which can propagate your tags to all the tag-able resources in the cfn template.